# Custom theme attribute

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, themes

So, on Android we have attributes like `colorPrimaryDark` which can be accessed by following way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Now, i have decided to create my own attribute. So, This is what i have done;

**Step 1** in attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources >
    <declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="colorLeadingDark" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Step 2** in Styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorLeadingDark">#9C27B0</item>
</style>
```

**Step 3** fab

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorLeadingDark"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

**Step 4** setup theme

I am setting up this theme `onCreate` in my Activity

when i run my code this works fine, without any issue. i can see my desired color of FAB. But, problem is when i click on FAB i got crash.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
```

Line 17 is the first line of FAB in XML declaration.

Following cases it works just fine:

- with `colorPrimaryDark` which is system define (this is telling me my code is fine)
- if i set the color programmatically by loading same color using `TypedArray typedArray=context.obtainStyledAttributes(getCurrentTheme(), attrs);`. (this is telling me my custom attribute implementation is correct.)

Now problem is only when i click. What am i doing wrong?